# How to constantly check if user is close to some coordinate from the list of coordinates? (for best performance)

Tags: ios, swift, core-data, ios8, core-location

I have a list of coordinates (about 100) in phone database.
I use core data for data access.
I use core location to track user location (work in background also)
In `didupdatelocation` method I fetch all locations and calculate distance 
between all of them with current location and notify user if he is for example 1000m away.
Problem is that this is slow and sometimes doesn't work.
What is the best solution for scenario like this?

Comment: Are those coordinates in the list scattered or contiguous? There might be some good heuristics based on the data property.

Comment: Scattered. User can add annotations om the map and each annotation is actually coordinate in the list.

Comment: kdtree can be a way to deal with problems like this, and it gives you log(n) search time, but I doubt it is worth it for 100 coordinates

Answer (score 0):

Devide space into regions. Save coordinates with region identifier into database. When you are checking the which coordinates close to you only fetch coordinates that is in the same region with your location and other regions that around your location's region.

For example the middle region is 00 the one that is one region right is 10, two region right is 20. If your location's region is 00 then you don't need to fetch coordinates from region 20 because they are too far away.

Hope this helps. I' m just saying first thing that comes my mind :)

Answer (score 0):

Just an idea:

One easy way to reduce the amount of computation you need to be doing would be to only calculate the distances every X location updates. E.g. discard the first 19 updates and calculate the distances after the 20th, discard the 19 following, use the 40th, ...

That way you could end up discarding 15 updates and after that the user remains stationary and no update is fired - would be bad. To prevent that, you could add a timer that triggers distance calculation half a second after the last update was called. Every time you actually calc the distance due to the previously described tactic, you would stop / reset the timer.